# Does Monge solution implies Kantorovich solution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, optimization

Let $X$ and $Z$ be arbitrary random variables with distributions $F_X$ and $F_Z$, respectively. Suppose that there exists an optimal transport map (in the sense of Monge problem), that is a map $m: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Z}$ such that $m_*(F_X)=F_Z$, where $m_*$ is the push-forward.

Is it true that the induced transport plan $(\operatorname{id}\times m)_*(F_X)$ is an optimal transport plan (in the sense of the Kantorovich problem)?